# Countdown timer with time format(00:00:00) in vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I am creating Access db which needs auto close the db using timer count down. for example, if I give 5 min then it should start count down displaying this time format 00:04:59

I have found several pieces of tips checking the web, but did not manage to fit the pieces to one working piece.

Below is working perfect. but in output i can see only min and sec 0:00. How to add code for hours as well (format 00:00:00)? I tried to add hours but it is not working

```
Public Loops As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.TimerInterval = 1000
Form_Timer
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()

Static StartTime As Date

Dim SecondsToCount As Integer

SecondsToCount = 15 'Set this variable to the total number of seconds to 
count down

If Loops = 0 Then StartTime = Time

Min = (SecondsToCount - DateDiff("s", StartTime, Time)) \ 60
Sec = (SecondsToCount - DateDiff("s", StartTime, Time)) Mod 60
Me.TimeLeft.Caption = "Form will close in " & Min & ":" & Format(Sec,"00")
Loops = Loops + 1

If Me.TimeLeft.Caption = "Form will close in 0:00" Then
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a textbox for display, `Timer` to get a better resolution, and a `TimerInterval` of 100 for a closer match.

Complete code-behind module of the form:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private WatchTime           As Date

Private Sub Form_Load()

    ' Specify count down time.
    Const CountDownSeconds  As Long = 15

    WatchTime = DateAdd("s", CountDownSeconds, Now)
    Me!txtCount.Value = WatchTime
    
    Me.TimerInterval = 100

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()

    Const SecondsPerDay     As Long = 86400
    
    Dim TimeLeft            As Date
    
    TimeLeft = CDate(WatchTime - Date - Timer / SecondsPerDay)
    Me!txtCount.Value = TimeLeft
    
    If TimeLeft <= 0 Then
        Me.TimerInterval = 0
        MsgBox "Time ran out!", vbExclamation, "Exit"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working but why its starts countdown from 12:00:00 am?. i am expecting output timer like 00:00:14. is this possible?

Comment: Can't tell. It runs fine here, so double-check your code.